# Does anyone have php code examples for the AddressVerify API on Paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm wanting to use the AddressVerify API to check if a user who's signing up to my website has an email address which is associated with a paypal account.

I've found:
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide.pdf

which is obviously very useful and also I've downloaded the php_nvp_samples.zip file which has all the code samples. But it doesn't seem to include the code to make an AddressVerify call.

I know I should probably be able to piece together something that would do the trick from the samples but I'm new and stupid and need help. Don't suppose anyone has some code to make an AddressVerify call which they don't mind sharing with me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fill out your API info in `CallserService.php`. Open a file like `TransactionDetails.php` and copy the 3 or 4 lines of code that make an NVP request. Replace the request it's making with the AddressVerify one and the parameters that requires instead. Run.

Comment: Have you written any code to try and do this yourself? I understand you are new to the community, and possibly to PHP, but the best way to learn is by doing. SO is here to help you with questions which arise whilst "doing", but this is not simply a place to ask people for pre-built code for you to reuse.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the pointer. Thats what I was looking for I think. I'm just a little unsure.

Comment: Hi Lucanos, thanks for the reply. I've written a little php but never had to do anything too complicated. Sorry for asking for code, I just thought if anyone had any they might like to share :( but the answer from Dan hopefully sets me on the right course. I am new to SO but loving it. I can't believe I've only just found what seems to be the most active and helpful coding forum on the 'net!

Comment: I actually posted some on https://www.x.com/thread/54135 yesterday. Have a look at that as well; it's a bit easier since it's only one single file.